# Why is this exponent relation true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I was doing a physics exercise, and all of a sudden, in the solution, it says that:
$$
\Delta(V^y) = y\Delta(V)V^{y-1}
$$
Why is this equation correct? How am I able to conclude that $\Delta(V^y)$ is indeed what it's saying that it is?!

**UPDATE:**

$V$ is volume

$y$ is a constant

$\Delta$ is change in volume, hence $\Delta(V) = V_f - V_i$

Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'll edit mate. one sec.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good call (+1). It was so easy to think $\Delta$ as a Laplace operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\Delta(v^y)=v^y\left(\left(1+\frac{\Delta v}{v}\right)^y-1\right)$$

Using the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) yields

$$\left(1+\frac{\Delta v}{v}\right)^y-1=y\left(\frac{\Delta v}{v}\right)+\underbrace{O\left(\left(\frac{\Delta v}{v}\right)^2\right)}_{\text{Higher Order Terms}}$$

where $f(x)=O(x)$ means that there exists a number $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le C|x|$ as $x\to 0$.  Here, we are taking $\Delta v$ to be "small."

Then, we have

$$\Delta(v^y)=yv^{y-1}\Delta v+v^yO\left(\left(\frac{\Delta v}{v}\right)^2\right)$$

Neglecting the Higher Order Terms gives

$$\Delta(v^y)=yv^{y-1}\Delta v$$

which is the sought expression.

Comment: mate, I think that the way you've explained is completely fine. The thing is that I don't have that maturity with math, And even with your explanation, It's a little bit hard to understand how do you see that you can write the first equation in a different way, and from that abstract everything... But good answer! Thank you for your time!

Comment: @BrunoReis You're welcome.  My pleasure.  If one is equipped with basic calculus, then an easy way to proceed is to note that the derivative of $v^y$ is $yv^{y-1}$.  Then, using differentials, we have $dv^y=yv^{y-1}dv$.

Comment: oooooooooooooooohhhhh my god!!!! How couldn't I think about that! haha perfect mate, just perfect your explanation with basis on calculus! Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoReis Pleased to hear you have it now! -Mark

Comment: you are amazing! Very polite... Can I have your email or any kind of contact? I'd like to chat more... Cya!

Comment: @BrunoReis Sure.  It's listed on my user profile page.  If you use it, please identify yourself; it's a business address.